# How to I stop debug messages from jetty from showing up in my log files

Tags: java, jetty, winrun4j

I have a web service written in Java, running on windows via WinRun4J and using Jetty for its web service.  When I start up the web service, I get a whole mess of DEBUG and INFO messages in my log file that look like this:

```
[Thread-2] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.[some class name] - loaded class com.sun.jersey.[more class stuff that changes from line to line]
```

Sometimes the messages are INFO instead of debug.  I am trying to make all of these messages NOT show up.  I've done a ton of reading around here.  Most posts always lead back to a solution that involves `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN` as a vmarg.  I have tried placing that in my `.ini` file (where all my args are for my WinRun4J service) but nothing seems to work.  Additionally, I tried placing `org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN` where I have my standard java log stuff (like `log.level=error`).

Here are a few of the 100s of lines being logged if it helps anyone make heads or tails of this.

```
1719 [Thread-2] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration  - file:/C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-9100-syslog-server-1.0.0.war-_-any-2067512562061944543.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar META-INF/resources checked
1719 [Thread-2] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration  - file:/C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-9100-syslog-server-1.0.0.war-_-any-2067512562061944543.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar META-INF/web-fragment.xml checked
1719 [Thread-2] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration  - file:/C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-9100-syslog-server-1.0.0.war-_-any-2067512562061944543.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/annotations-2.0.1.jar META-INF/resources checked
```

Answer (score -1):

The logging configuration you have is setup to allow the named loggers at `org.eclipse.jetty` to emit at DEBUG level.

Based on your logging output, you are not using default jetty logging, but appear to have setup some other logging framework.

You need to edit your logging configuration files to set logging for the named loggers at `org.eclipse.jetty` to the `INFO` level or higher (eg: WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF)